# Does CMS systems like Orchard or WordPress have RSS feed for comments?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, orchardcms

I would like to aggregate posts from different already existing blogs on my website. I want to show blog title and number of comments. The blogs already exists and I don't own them.

Do the most common CMSs provide RSS feed for comments by default so I can show number of comment next to each blog post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reply for wordpress, and the answer is **Yes** ...
( although probably true for most CMS )

The wordpress comments RSS feed url can be retrieved via

```
<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url'); ?>
```

For a single post it would be a template tag

```
<?php post_comments_feed_link('RSS 2.0'); ?>
```

The site comments default URL would be

```
http://example.com/?feed=comments-rss2
```

And you can even control the single post comment link with

```
   post_comments_feed_link( $link_text = 'link_text', $post_id = 'post_id',
         $feed = 'feed_type' );
```

You can read more about wordpress feeds in the mighty [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Orchard supports the generation of RSS feeds on any content type, not just posts and comments, but by default, comment feeds are not typically exposed on blogs managed by Orchard. You'd need the cooperation from the person managing the blog so that they add it.

In general, it's easy to discover what feeds any site exposes no matter what CMS (if any) is used to manage it. Just view the source, and look for link tags with  `type="application/rss+xml"` attribute. The `href` on those tags points to the feeds.